# support.v7 v21.0.0 library and ActionBarDrawerToggle width

Tags: android

I want to use new support library appcompat 21.0.0, for switch compatibility.

So to build my project with the new library, I changed `compileSdkVersion` to 21.

But now, my ActionBarDrawerToggle became wide as normal actionbar button, from narrow.

How can I keep toggle narrow like [this](https://developer.android.com/design/media/navigation_drawer_holo_dark_light.png) with new library version

PS: Can I move to new **v7**.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle, but make it narrow as **v4** old style?